# Function arity of a first-class function

Tags: php, type-theory

I'm rewriting PHP type system and working on implementation of a more pure language. I'm implementing as much as I can in question of purism as functional and object-oriented language, like method-chaining, types as objects, message-passing, conditionals as methods and some other features http://github.com/haskellcamargo/rawr. In this, functions will be instance of  `Func` class and after I'll do a transcompiler for it, because PHP has gone so far as it is. `Func` will not limit to unary functions as parameters, but will check if, when called, the number of arguments matches **exactly** the  number of expected arguments:

```
$add = Func(function(Number $x) {
  return Func(function(Number $y) use ($x) {
    return $x -> add ($y);
  });
});
```

Where add will be a function where I don't need to control its arity, as much as it is unary and works by currying. But when I work with functions that receive multiple parameters, my problem appears. Let's take as example a simple function that outputs a name in the screen:

```
$say_name = Func(function(String $name) {
  $name -> outputln();
});
```

`$say_name` requires **1 unique parameter** but how can I assert that it will receive **n** parameters, being **n** the arity of this anonymous function?

`$say_name -> invoke("Test");` might work, but `$say_name -> invoke("Test", 1);` also works because I'm not getting a way to know the arity of a anonymous function.

`function () { return func_num_args(); }`

This will return the number of arguments passed to it. I need to know the number of **required arguments** to `x`, something like:

`function x(Int $i, Functor $j) { return a_magic_function_that_returns_it_all(); }`

And outputs me something like `array(2) { [0]=> Int [1]=> Functor }`. Can somebody help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with usage of `ReflectionFunction`:

```
 $add = function($x, $y) { return $x + $y; };
 $x = new ReflectionFunction($add);
 $args = $x->getParameters();
 var_dump(count($args)); // 2
```